# How to rerender a component every time a value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I'm making a sudoku solver, and I have the actual solver working. However, I want the sudoku solver to be sort of 'animated' and every time one of the tiles changes I want that change to be shown. With the way I have it written currently it will only re render once the whole sudoku is solved.

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './SudokuSolver.css'

export default function SudokuSolver() {
  //0 stands for empty
  const sudoku = [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                  0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                  0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 0,
                  0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 7, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
                  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8,
                  0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                  0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
  const [sudokuObject, setSudokuObject] = useState(sudoku.map(tile => {
    return {
      value: tile,
      predetermined: tile !== 0 ? true : false
    }
  }))
  const sudokuSize = Math.sqrt(sudoku.length)
  const tileSizeInPixels = 70;
  
  const pixelsFromTop = (index) => {
    const subsectionBuffer = Math.floor((index / sudokuSize) / Math.sqrt(sudokuSize)) * 20
    return ((Math.floor(index / sudokuSize)) * tileSizeInPixels) + subsectionBuffer
  }

  const pixelsFromLeft = (index) => {
    const subsectionBuffer = Math.floor((index % sudokuSize) / 3) * 20; 
    return ((index % sudokuSize) * tileSizeInPixels) + subsectionBuffer
  }

  const isLegalByRow = (testNum, index, sudokuObject) => {
    //get the row number (possible values: 0 through sudokuSize)
    const rowNum = Math.floor(index / sudokuSize)
    for(let i = 0; i < sudokuSize; i++){
      if(sudokuObject[i + (rowNum * sudokuSize)].value === testNum)
        return false
    }
    return true
  }

  const isLegalByColumn = (testNum, index, sudokuObject) => {
    //get the column number (possible values: 0 through sudokuSize)
    const columnNum = (index) % (sudokuSize)
    for(let i = 0; i < sudokuSize; i++){
      if(sudokuObject[(i * sudokuSize) + columnNum].value === testNum)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  const isLegalBySubsection = (testNum, index, sudokuObject) => {
    const subsectionSize = Math.sqrt(sudokuSize)
    const rowNum = Math.floor(index / sudokuSize)
    const columnNum = index % sudokuSize 
    //gets 'subsection indexes', for instance in a 9x9 grid there's 9 subsections (3x3) boxes
    //this determines which box to check
    const subsectionRow = Math.floor(rowNum / Math.sqrt(sudokuSize))
    const subsectionColumn = Math.floor(columnNum / Math.sqrt(sudokuSize))
    //example: box [1, 1] should check indexes: 30, 31, 32, 39, 40, 41, 48, 49, 50
    const subsectionRowSize = subsectionSize * sudokuSize
    const startingIndex = subsectionRowSize * subsectionRow + (subsectionColumn * subsectionSize)
    for(let i = 0; i < subsectionSize; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < subsectionSize; j++){
        if(sudokuObject[(startingIndex + j) + i * sudokuSize].value === testNum)
          return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  
  const isLegal = (testNum, index, tempObject) => {
    return(isLegalBySubsection(testNum, index, tempObject) && 
    isLegalByRow(testNum, index, tempObject) && isLegalByColumn(testNum, index, tempObject))
  }
 const autoSolveSudoku = () => {
    /* the algorithm: 
      iterate through each tile of the sudoku, for each tile:
        starting at the number 1, try every possible number (up to 9 for a standard sudoku)
        stop at a number when it's legal and go forward to the next tile
        if(none of the possible numbers are legal):
          go back to previous tiles(again skip if predetermined),
          on previous tiles: 
           start at the number that was left there and go up to sudokuSize
           once a legal number is found start going forward again
           if no legal number is found keep going backward
    */
    let goingForward = true;
    let tempObject = [...sudokuObject];
    for(let i = 0; i < tempObject.length; i++){
      if(tempObject[i].predetermined){
        if(goingForward)
          continue;
        i -=2;
        continue;
      }
      for(let j = tempObject[i].value; j <= sudokuSize; j++){
        if(j === 0){
          continue;
        }
        if(!goingForward && tempObject[i].value === sudokuSize){
          tempObject[i].value = 0;
          break;
        }
        if(isLegal(j, i, tempObject)){
          tempObject[i].value = j;
          goingForward = true;
          break;
        }
        if(j === sudokuSize){
          tempObject[i].value = 0;
          goingForward = false;
        }
       
      }
      if(!goingForward)
        i -= 2
        setSudokuObject(tempObject)
    }
    
  }

  return <div style={{top:'50px', left:'50px', position:'relative'}}>
    {sudokuObject.map((tile, index) => {
      return <div id="tile" style={{top: pixelsFromTop(index), left: pixelsFromLeft(index), color: tile.predetermined && 'blueviolet'}}>
        
        {index - 1 % 9 === 0 && index !== 1 && index !== 0 && <br/>}
        {tile.value !== 0 ? tile.value : " "}
      </div> 
    })}
    <button id='solvebutton' onClick={autoSolveSudoku}>Auto Solve</button>

  </div>
}
```

I know setSudokuObject() would only be called once the autoSolveSudoku() function finishes, so is there a way to update it every time a value changes? Honestly I've never encountered this before so I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: To clarify the question -- are you looking for the numbers to come up one at a time with a delay between each or something?

Comment: @adsy so on startup and after its solved this is how my sudoku is currently being rendered: https://imgur.com/a/WmgTWam , I want every number that's in black to be rendered every time it changes. Yes some type of delay so the user can actually see what's being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` hook in ReactJS.

This is an example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  },[count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the code above, each time that the value in the `counter` changes, the things which are in the `useEffect` hook will execute again.

So, in general this is how you can use it:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // Codes you want to execute each time that variableYouWantToControl changes. 
},[variableYouWantToControl]
```

## Note

The variable that want to control it (in the example above: `counter`), should be of the type `useState`. So, if you define a variable like `let counter = 0`, it won't work. It should be defined like `const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)` and then you should the value of `counter` by: `setCounter(1)`.

Comment: I failed to include in my post, but I did try this. I tried moving tempObject out of the autoSolveFunction and doing something like this: 
let tempObject = [...sudokuObject];
  let count = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    setSudokuObject([...tempObject])
  }, [count])
and then increasing count every time something changes, but it doesn't seem to be working still

Comment: I added a `Note` section to my answer to complete it according to your comment.

Comment: From my understanding of useState(), it won't actually be called until the function completely finishes. So for example if I put setCount(count => count + 1) it in the autoSolveSudoku() function it won't be called until the sudoku is completely solved. I verified this by trying and logging count at every iteration. It's 0 like 49,000 times and then jumps straight to 49,000 after the function is finished

Comment: It is because `tempObject` is not defined using `useState`. Define it the same way you defined `sudokuObject` and the dependency array should be [temObject]. Then, in your function called `autoSolveFunction`, each time you change `tempObject` during solving sudoku, you can see it will re-render.

Comment: but if I call setTempObject() every time I want to change something won't it be the same issue where it won't actually change until the function's completed? If I do that I can't go tempObject[i].value = x since it would be a const so I would have to make another copy of sudokuObject so I can do setTempObject(tempObject2)? Not sure if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Technically, with useState, you can do many things and not just assign the final result to it. I think it's better for you to search and learn more about this hook in react as this is one of the main differences from pure js. You can add, remove, assign, etc using the same tempObject even if you define it by useState. Just the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you probably want to turn your sudoku solver into a resumable function that solves exactly one step, calls `setSudokuObject` with the new result, and then terminates to be called again once the button is clicked repeatedly. In the meantime, React will re-render your component.

To do that, the variables relevant for the outer loop could be turned into React states:

```
  const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState(0);
  const [goingForward, setGoingForward] = useState(true);
```

Afterwards, they can inform the algorithm of the previous state:

```
for (let i = lastLocation; i < tempObject.length; i++) {
```

If the move is legal, the `solveStep` function updates the grid and returns:

```
        if (isLegal(j, i, tempObject)) {
          tempObject[i].value = j;
          setSudokuObject(tempObject);
          setLastLocation(i);
          setGoingForward(true);
          return;
        }
        if (j === sudokuSize) {
          tempObject[i].value = 0;
          // Here, I am not sure whether the `goingForward` variable 
          // will be updated for the current loop correctly. Experiment! :)
          setGoingForward(false);
        }
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to implement buttons for "Solve 10 steps" and "Solve 50 steps".